# div Slightly moves when browser resize on css transform property rotate perspective stuff

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apply this class to a div to get a isometric look, and when I resize the window The div slightly moves, what does cause it, how can I prevent it.

```
.isometric {
  perspective: 5000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

It doesn't happen on codepen: https://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/GNxeYN

Comment: Make a videos and share so that we know what is the problem. I think it might be due to the vertical scroll bar. Please give overflow:hidden; to the body and then try.

Comment: overflow:hidden doesn't work, and it's not related to scrollbar. It doesn't happen if I remove `preserve-3d` though. Just try this code on chrome and resize window. It looks like the perspective changes